How to add an iframe with inline script to my Next.js project?
I have the following iframe to add to my Next.js project.
<iframe
  class="plot"
  aria-label="Map"
  id="datawrapper-chart-${id}"
  src="https://datawrapper.dwcdn.net/${id}/1/"
  style="width: 0; min-width: 100% !important; overflow: scroll; flex-grow: 1"
  data-external="1"
></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
  !(function () {
    "use strict";
    window.addEventListener("message", function (a) {
      if (void 0 !== a.data["datawrapper-height"]) {
        var e = document.querySelectorAll("iframe");
        for (var t in a.data["datawrapper-height"])
          for (var r = 0; r < e.length; r++)
            if (e[r].contentWindow === a.source) {
              var i = a.data["datawrapper-height"][t] + "px";
              e[r].style.height = i;
            }
      }
    });
  })();
</script>


I tried using dangerouslySetInnerHTML and it did work, but I wonder if there's a more "React" way to do it.
The ways below didn't work.


You don't have to use script tag for that this is the react way of doing it
// components/DataWrapperChart.js

import { useEffect } from 'react';

const DataWrapperChart = ({ id }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleMessage = (event) => {
      if (event.data["datawrapper-height"]) {
        const iframes = document.querySelectorAll("iframe");
        for (let iframe of iframes) {
          if (iframe.contentWindow === event.source) {
            const height = event.data["datawrapper-height"][id] + "px";
            iframe.style.height = height;
          }
        }
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener("message", handleMessage);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("message", handleMessage);
    };
  }, [id]);

  return (
    <iframe
      className="plot"
      aria-label="Map"
      id={`datawrapper-chart-${id}`}
      src={`https://datawrapper.dwcdn.net/${id}/1/`}
      style={{ width: '0', minWidth: '100% !important', overflow: 'scroll', flexGrow: '1' }}
      data-external="1"
    ></iframe>
  );
};

export default DataWrapperChart;


then we can use it in some page like this
// pages/somepage.js

import DataWrapperChart from '../components/DataWrapperChart';

const SomePage = () => {
  const chartId = "your-chart-id";

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Your Page</h1>
      <DataWrapperChart id={chartId} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default SomePage;


